# How to prove an inequality with power

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

How to prove that there exist a constant $c>0$ such that

$$(a^{4/3}+b^{4/3})\le c(a^2+b^2)^{1/3} $$

for all $a,b\ge 0$?

Thanks

Comment: There is no way such inequality may hold since it is not homogeneous. Map $(a,b)$ into $\lambda(a,b)$ for some $\lambda>0$.

Comment: @ exactly. [See this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximize+%5Cdfrac%7Bx%5E%7B4%2F3%7D%2By%5E%7B4%2F3%7D%7D%7B(x%5E2%2By%5E2)%5E%7B1%2F3%7D%7D+on+x%3E0,+y%3E0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x= a^{1/3}$ and $y=b^{1/3}$ so we have to find $c$ such: $$(x^4+y^4)^3 \leq d(x^6+y^6)$$
where $d = c^3$ so we have for $y=1$: $$f(x):={(x^4+1)^3\over x^6+1}\leq d$$
since $f$ is unbounded such $d$ **doesn't exist** and so $c$ also doesn't exist.

Comment: yes but how we can find it?

Comment: @siwar: you cannot, see my comment above.

Comment: and is it possible to find a constant such that $$(a^{4/3}+b^{4/3})\le c(a+b)^{2/3}$$?

Comment: In that case it does exist.

Comment: But that is new question.

Comment: in fact i am trying to prove the following inequaly with opeartors:$$\langle u,|x|^{\frac{4}{3}}u\rangle+\langle u,|D_x|^{\frac{4}{3}}u\rangle\le c||\Big((|D_x|+|x|)\Big)^{\frac{2}{3}}u||_{L^2(\mathbb{R})}$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know this operators.

Answer (score 1):

By the generalized mean inequality, what you can say is that

$$ \left(\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\right)^\frac12 \ge \left(\frac{a^{\frac43}+b^{\frac43}}{2}\right)^\frac34 \implies  \left(\frac{a^{\frac43}+b^{\frac43}}{2}\right)\le \left(\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\right)^\frac23 \\
\implies a^{\frac43}+b^{\frac43}\le 2^\frac13\left(a^2+b^2\right)^\frac23 $$

and if the RHS is $\le1$, we have

$$a^{\frac43}+b^{\frac43}\le 2^\frac13\left(a^2+b^2\right)^\frac23\le 2^\frac16\left(a^2+b^2\right)^\frac13$$

Comment: How do you prove the inequality $\left(\frac{a^2+b^2}{2}\right)^\frac12 \ge \left(\frac{a^{\frac43}+b^{\frac43}}{2}\right)^\frac34 $? thanks

Comment: @siwar that is the generalized mean inequality https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean

Comment: i don't see what are $x_i$ is our case?

Comment: a and b, n=2 and p=2 and 4/3

Comment: @siwar It is not useful discuss by comments, you can ask another OP for others questions

Comment: i post my question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2623752/proving-an-inequality-with-power