# Proving an inequality with power

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I want to prove that there exist a constant $c>0$ such that

$$\left(a^\frac43+b^\frac43\right)\le   c\Big(\left(1+a^2\right)^\frac23+\left(1+b^2\right)^\frac23\Big)$$

for all $a,b\ge 0$

Thanks for help

Comment: Prove that the values $\frac {a^{4/3} +b^{4/3}}{(1+a^2)^{23} + (1+b^2)^{2/3}}$ is bounded above.

Comment: yes it is the same question but how to prove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left(1+a^2\right)^\frac23+\left(1+b^2\right)^\frac23
> \left(a^2\right)^{\frac23} + \left(b^2\right)^{\frac23}
= a^{\frac43} + b^{\frac43}.$

Comment: that is perfect!

Comment: @siwar Sure, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The inequality with $c=1$ is trivial and such inequality is optimal/sharp by considering $(a,b)=(M,M)$ with $M\to +\infty$.